# Combine two (tables or lists) to create output of unique combinations in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Trying to combine two queries in Power BI to have an output of unique combinations.

for instance one list(or column): A, B, C

and another list(or column): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7

Output should be: A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6, A7, B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, C7

Is there a way to accomplish this? (Yes my rows are not equal in count)
Just don't know the best or right approach for this (tried using combine with a helper column and hit a dead end as duplicates get created, unless I did that wrong)

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially a Cartesian product (a.k.a. cross product) of two lists.

If you just have two text lists, you can do a one-liner like this:

```
List.Combine(List.Transform(List1, (L1) => List.Transform(List2, (L2) => L1 & L2)))
```

This says for each item X in the first list, create a list that is the second list with X prepended to each element. This gives a list of lists that is flattened out to a single list using the combine function.

---

It's not uncommon to want to do this with table though too. In this case, the analogous idea is to define a new column on one table where each row is the entire list/column of the other and then expand that new column.

Assuming we want the cross product of `Table1[Column1]` and `Table2[Column2]`:

```
let
    Table1 = <Table1 Source>,
    AddCustom = Table.AddColumn(Table1 , "Custom", each Table2),
    Expand = Table.ExpandTableColumn(AddCustom, "Custom", {"Column2"}, {"Column2"}),
    Concatenate = Table.AddColumn(Expand, "Concatenate", each [Column1] & [Column2])
in
    Concatenate
```

**Edit:**
You can do the concatenation before the expand too:

```
let
    Table1 = <Table1 Source>,
    AddCustom = Table.AddColumn(Table1 , "Custom",
                    (T1) => List.Transform(Table2[Column2], each T1[Column1] & _)),
    Expanded = Table.ExpandListColumn(AddCustom, "Custom")
in
    Expanded
```

---

References with more detail:

[Cartesian Product Joins](https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2016/05/11/cartesian-product-joins-for-the-excel-person/)

[Cartesian Join of two queries...](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Cartesian-Join-of-two-queries-to-create-new-table-with-a-record/td-p/148405)

Comment: Would this be easier as a list or a table? In power bi it is readily able to go either way, but what would be advised or recommended?

Comment: Whatever makes more sense for your workflow or whichever feels more comfortable for you.

Comment: also does data type matter for this step?

Comment: it worked!! thank you so much, also they are all unique values which is perfect!!

Comment: Type matters in that you'll have to convert non-text types to text to append them.

Comment: for the tabular option, what would be the way to reference a column from a different table query??

Comment: `TableName[ColumnName]`. That's a list instead of a table like `Table2` in my example.

Comment: Is there a way to concatenate into the same column as the "Expand" step??

Comment: You can probably do a `Table.TransformColumns` with similar logic as the `List.Transform` in my answer.

Comment: I will try it out! Thank you so much!

Comment: That isn't working. I know I stumbled upon a solution that worked yesterday. For whatever reason that change was not applied to the model, but I nested the '&' concatenation into the "expand' step somehow and it took

Comment: You can do the concatenation before the expand more easily. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Just create another column in the first table with same value for all rows. for example 1. do the same thing in the second table. join/merge these two tables on that new column of each table. Since the same value repeating for all values, you will get your all-possible-combinations result.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).